# Utf8 character set encoding error while data insertion using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

I am facing issues to insert Bulgarian language string using perl script in mysql. If I do manual insertion using query then it's working fine but while using perl it convert that string in to unknown characters.

I have perform below steps to resolve that issue but still no luck.

Set utf8 character set in database connection

```
$dbh->do("set character set utf8");
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');
$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
```

Also i have set default character set utf8 from my.cnf file.

Still I am getting Unknown characters.

Can any one suggest me how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You also need to make sure that Perl knows what encoding your strings are. If you're not already familiar with that, start by reading the `perlunitut` man page.

Comment: You need to show your code. There are any number of things that could be wrong. Broadly, you should *decode* any character strings coming from external data sources and *encode* any output data. `use utf8` at the top of your program if you are using any non-ASCII characters in the code itself

Comment: What does "I am getting Unknown characters" mean exactly?

Comment: Please provide a ten-line script that demonstrates the problem. We don't know what you did wrong if you don't show us.

Answer (score 0):

See if these help:

```
use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

It's not just MySQL that could be screwing things up -- the original bytes could be mis-encoded; the output could be improperly rendered; etc.

If you have some data stored, let's check to see if they are 'correct'.  Do something like

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

`ДЖ` should come out as hex `D094D096` if it is correctly encoded in utf8.  Note that Cyrillic mostly has `D0xx` hex for its characters.

I have more discussion [here](http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/charcoll#cyrillic_macedonian_etc).

Comment: Thanks for your reply
for select its working fine but i have an issue for insertion data in mysql after select it from DB.

Comment: The `SET NAMES utf8` that you are doing should establish that the bytes in the client are utf8-encoded.  Do you have any more clues?

Comment: if i do print query then it show me correct value but while that query process using perl drivers that time not getting correct value in Mysql.

If same query try in mysql then also i get perfect value only its not working using perl drivers.

Comment: It is not the driver, it is establishing the character set.